# What is the meaning of "mode" in the following code?

Tags: lua

```
    function setup()
      return {
        properties = {

        default_mode              = mode.driving,                                    
        default_speed             = 10,        
        oneway_handling           = true,
        side_road_multiplier      = 0.8,                 
        turn_penalty              = 7.5,
        speed_reduction           = 0.8,
        turn_bias                 = 1.075,
        cardinal_directions       = false
}}
```

I'm reading a piece of code and got deeply confused about the meaning of "default_mode = mode.driving". I mean, what is this "mode"? Is it a variable a maybe a table? A not-defined table I guess? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this the full section of code you have available? `mode` is likely a `module`(something like `mode = require('modes')`) or is a table defined globally or in code that is not visible in the section provided.

Comment: @Nifim, so you mean, mode comes from the require part in the beginning of the file, right?

Comment: It's either a requirement of itself, i.e `require 'mode'`, or `mode.driving` is a method defined elsewhere in the file.